# ionic 2: Fab button with label

Tags: label, ionic2, floating-action-button

I am building an app using ionic 2 following the documentation. I have implemented a fab button with a fab-list. I am trying to put a descriptive label next to the containing buttons. It seems that there is no way to put a label next to floating buttons with ionic 2 out of the box. I have looked to a couple questions about it on stackoverflow and on github.

It is strange that such a basic feature has not been implemented in ionic 2...

Is there an easy way to put a description label next to a floating button in ionic 2?

Thanks

Comment: you might find this worth a go https://market.ionic.io/plugins/ionic-fab-toolbar

Comment: Have you got it done, anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Into the latest Ionic Framework you could show the labels for the IonFabButton as follows:

[image]

This is an Ionic-React example:

**1. Paste the following into your corresponding .css file**

```
ion-fab-button[data-desc] {
    position: relative;
}

ion-fab-button[data-desc]::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: attr(data-desc);
    z-index: 1;
    right: 55px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: var(--ion-color-light);
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 1px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
```

**2. You need to use data-desc attribute of your IonFabButton to set the label**

```
<IonFab vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
    <IonFabButton>
        <IonIcon icon={add} />
    </IonFabButton>
    <IonFabList side="top">
        <IonFabButton routerLink="/documents" data-desc="Upload Document">
            <IonIcon icon={folderOpen} color="warning" />
        </IonFabButton>
        <IonFabButton routerLink="/leave" data-desc="Apply for Leave">
          <IonIcon icon={calendarOutline} color="secondary" />
        </IonFabButton>
        <IonFabButton routerLink="/expenses"  data-desc="New Expense">
          <IonIcon icon={cardOutline} color="success" />
        </IonFabButton>
        <IonFabButton routerLink="/timesheet"  data-desc="New Timesheet">
          <IonIcon icon={timeOutline} color="primary" />
        </IonFabButton>
    </IonFabList>
</IonFab>
```

Answer (score 1):

This Worked For me Magnificently

```
    <ion-fab bottom right>
            <button ion-fab ><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></button>
          <ion-fab-list side="top">

            <button ion-fab >
              <ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
              <div class="label">Facebook</div>
            </button>

            <button ion-fab >
              <ion-icon name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon>
              <div  class="label" dir="rtl">Instagram </div>
            </button>

            <button ion-fab >
              <ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
              <div  class="label" dir="rtl">Twitter</div>
            </button>

            <button ion-fab >
              <ion-icon name="logo-whatsapp"></ion-icon>
              <div  class="label" dir="rtl">Whatsapp</div>
            </button>

          </ion-fab-list>
        </ion-fab>
```

CSS :

```
.fab {
    contain: initial;
}

ion-fab {
    ion-fab-list button[ion-fab] {
      overflow: visible;

      div.label {
        position: absolute;
        right: 48px;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
        height: 24px;
        line-height: 16px;
        padding: 5px 8px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        color: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
  }
```